# Google Vision API - OCR - Separate Paragraph/Line Issue (Java)

Tags: java, pdf, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

We are using Vision API for a project and we've got an issue about text recognition from a PDF file. Vision API recognizes different lines as paragraphs. They are inferior lines. Like this:

```
1. Header

Company Name
Company Address
Telephone: +90 222 111 22 33
Fax: +90 222 1112233
```

Vision API recognizes first row as one paragraph. It is ok, we want it. But it also recognizes the other 4 lines as 1 paragraph. We want to them line by line. What can we do?

And thanks for your interest!

Comment: public vision api are not flexible like that, they are very generic and there's no guarantee that you'll get the structure that you want. You can review the docs: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf in order to understand what are your options. But also consider how much generic your input is, and what can you do on your side.

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is sad. Do you know any alternative OCR program of this? @Pievis

Comment: There are other alternatives but you might get the same result, there's rekognition, microsoft computer vision, SemaMediaData. However what it might be more helpful is understanding what you need to do and maybe wrap your logic around the vision api's result. You can try to add the payload to the question, maybe what you need might be there in some form :)

Comment: Thank you so much. We will try other services and try new logic for recognize :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing embedded newlines in the text coming back from Google, then you can traverse the contents of the paragraph structure down through the Word and Symbol (i.e., character) objects, and can check for the existence of a property on each symbol that is the detected break after the symbol.  You can distinguish between end of line breaks and other kinds of breaks, and split the lines of the paragraph at the end of line break points.

Roughly, if you were to do this in Clojure, it'd look like:

```
(def space-breaks #{(.getNumber TextAnnotation$DetectedBreak$BreakType/SURE_SPACE)
                    (.getNumber TextAnnotation$DetectedBreak$BreakType/SPACE)
                    })

(def line-breaks #{(.getNumber TextAnnotation$DetectedBreak$BreakType/EOL_SURE_SPACE)
                   (.getNumber TextAnnotation$DetectedBreak$BreakType/LINE_BREAK)})


(defn get-paragraph-text [paragraph]
  (let [words (.getWordsList paragraph)
        symbols (mapcat #(getSymbolsList %) words)
        sb (StringBuilder.)]
    (reduce (fn [last-break next-symbol]
              (let [sym (.getText  next-symbol)]
                (cond (line-breaks last-break) (do (.append sb "\n") (.append sb sym))
                      (space-breaks last-break) (do (.append sb " ") (.append sb sym))
                      :else (.append sb sym))
                (when (.hasProperty next-symbol)) 
                  (.getNumber (.getType (.getDetectedBreak (.getProperty next- symbol)))))))
             nil symbols)
    (clojure.string/split (str sb) #"\n")))
```

This'd produce a sequence of strings, one per line.

Comment: Thanks for interest. We found another alternate(Cloudmersive) for our project and implement it. I will try your advice for another projects.